# Tkinter - Forward string variable to a class in different file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am building a small app for some data analysis.
I have a Tkinter Main page where I create a Label with a variable( a file name). Now, I would like to pass this filename to a method placed in a different file.

In the code, I have the btn_web_report calling the function read_excel placed in the second file. I would like to have as input in the read_excel(data) the value of loaded_data which is a StringVar().
When I am trying to print the string, I do not get anything.

Normally, when all my code is in one file, I can read it with .get(), but it is not working here.

Can anyone shed some light into my problem?
Thank you in advance!

Below is the part of the code:

Main file:

```
class GuiOutRep(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        global loaded_data


        ##############################################################################
        # individual frames

        # ============================================================================
        # read data frame
        read_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        read_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)   

        # ============================================================================
        # analysis frame
        analysis_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        analysis_frame.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4)

        # ============================================================================
        # quit
        quit_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        quit_frame.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=4)


        ##############################################################################
        # insert label for loaded file
       
        loaded_data = StringVar()
        lbl_data = tk.Label(
            read_frame,
            textvariable = loaded_data,
            font = "Times 9 italic",
            fg = "#000000")
        lbl_data.grid(row=1, column=0, padx = 5, pady=5)





        ##############################################################################
        # buttons
        # ============================================================================
        # load data
        # tkinter used for file dialog for picking required results file
        def get_file():
            file_path = fd.askopenfilename(title='Select data you must!', 
                filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xls*")])
            #path=os.path.dirname(file_path)
            #file=os.path.basename(file_path)
            loaded_data.set(file_path) # print on screen 
            return file_path, loaded_data


        btn_load_data = ttk.Button(
            read_frame, 
            text='Load data', 
            command=get_file, 
            width=22)
        btn_load_data.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=0, pady=10)



        # ============================================================================
        # create html report



        # ============================================================================
        # create web interface
        wbrep = Web_report
        btn_web_report = ttk.Button(
            analysis_frame,
            text='Custom analysis',
            command=wbrep.read_excel(loaded_data),
            width=22)
        btn_web_report.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=0, pady=10)

        # ============================================================================
        # quit
        def quit():
            root.destroy()
        
        ttk.Button(quit_frame, text='Exit', command=quit).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)


        # ============================================================================
        # analysis





# ============================================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    outrep = GuiOutRep(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Second file:

```
class Web_report:

    def read_excel(data):
    #    file = lbl_data.get()
    #    xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        print(data.get()) 
            #number = len(xl.sheet_names)
```

Comment: I'm not able to run your code at the moment but I can see a couple of problems. First, your instance of `wbrep = Web_report` should be `wbrep = Web_report()` and method `read_excel` requires `self` as the first parameter.

Comment: Hello Derek, first of all, thank you for your answer. Well, it might be that I am doing a second error - my code is running like that. I just do not understand how to give the required string to the function or how to make the function read the string from the Tkinter interface. Regarding self, this is also something I believe is wrong, but, if I enter self and a second variable, I do not get it working. So, you see, absolute beginner!

Comment: Try changing `btn_web_report` button command to `command = lambda x = loaded_data: wbrep.read_excel(x),`